# What should I do when I have a blocking thing in the on_message tornado.websocket?

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I'm new to tornado.I am trying to build a chat server proxy with tornado,I got the message from the web client,normally it just need to send it back,however,i need to send those message to another server first,here comes the problem,it costs a lot of time to wait the other server response,i need to make it no-blocking,but when i use the anonymous methods of the tornado,it doesn't work at all,help me,thank you very much!

That's the part of my  pseudo code：

```
class ClientWSConnectienter(websocket.WebSocketHandler):

_thread_pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(20)

def initialize(self, room_handler):
    #chat room initiate
    self.__rh = room_handler

@run_on_executor(executor='_thread_pool')
def worker(self,msg):
    #send the msg to another server
    pmessage=send_msg_to_server(msg) 
    return pmessage

@tornado.web.asynchronous
@tornado.gen.coroutine
def on_message(self, message):
    #this will blocking for too much time,and I want make it no-blocking
    pmessage=yeild worker(msg) 
    #send the recive pmessage to others client
    room.write_message(pmessage) 
    self.finish()
```

obviously,it doesn't work,I got something like this:

```
error:websocket cannot use this method
```

So,what should I do? thanks a lot

But after I reedit my code,it still blocks in the task part.I don't know why,this is still part of my code
Re_edit:

```
class ClientWSConnection(websocket.WebSocketHandler):

def initialize(self, room_handler):
    self.queue = tornado.queues.Queue()

def open(self, client_id):
    IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(self.loop)

def on_message(self, message):
    self.queue.put(msg)

def on_close(self):
    self.queue.put(None)

@coroutine
def loop(self):
    while 1:
        msg=yield self.queue.get()
        if msg is None:
            return
        msg=yield self.worker(msg)
        pmessage = msg
        room.write_message(pmessage)
@coroutine
def worker(self,msg):
    #need to send the other server,blocking here
    time.sleep(10)
    raise Return(msg)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that error message is coming from your call to `finish()`, which is not meaningful for websockets (did you mean `close()`?). (Also, there's no need to use both `@asynchronous` and `@coroutine`; `@coroutine` alone is sufficient)

But there's a bigger problem: Remember that when overriding methods defined in a superclass, you can only make them a coroutine if the documentation says you can (because coroutines are called differently from regular methods). `WebSocketHandler.on_message` does not currently (as of Tornado 4.3) support coroutines.

So you need to use a queue to hand this off to another task. Something like this:

```
class MyHandler(WebSocketHandler):
    def initialize(self):
        self.queue = tornado.queues.Queue()

    def on_open(self):
        IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(self.loop)

    def one_message(self, msg):
        self.queue.put(msg)

    def on_connection_close(self):
        self.queue.put(None)

    @coroutine
    def loop(self):
        while True:
            msg = yield self.queue.get()
            if msg is None:
                return
            pmessage = yield self.worker(msg)
            self.write_message(pmessage)
```

Comment: Thank you very much,master,I'm so glad to have your answer,i mean,your're so awesome.And I have changed my code,but still haven't sovled that problem,it'll be nice to have your response again.The new code in the question reedit,thank you again

Comment: Thank you very much